# how to use custom fonts and draw a text in html canvas using the graphics context

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am making a web multiplayer game with nodejs. I am drawing the name of the players in the canvas as text.
All I want is, to know how to use the custom font which I have loaded, to draw the text in html canvas using the graphics context. I loaded the font in css using the @font-face rule. this is how I tried  ↓

**CSS -**

```css
@font-face {

font-family: "olden-empire";
src: url('path-to-the-font.ttf');

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT -**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var graphicsContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
graphicsContext.font = "20px olden-empire";
graphicsContext.fillText("hello world", 100, 100);
```

The font is not getting applied to the "hello world" text. It is using the default font.
The font that I have loaded is working for the html elements, but not for canvas drawing. Is this possible? if yes please say some solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that you are drawing the text on the canvas before the font is loaded.

You will also be displaying the 'ordinary' HTML text maybe before the font is loaded but the system will understand that and go back and rerender that text in the font once it's available. It can't do the same for the canvas text because once you've drawn the text on the canvas there is no 'memory' that it was text - by then it's just a load of points on a canvas.

So, wait for the font to load before using it on the canvas.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts) gives this example:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
  // Any operation that needs to be done only after all the fonts
  // have finished loading can go here.
});
```

though you'll probably want to be a bit more cautious just in case there's an error and catch that situation with something like this:

```
document.fonts.ready
  .then(() => {
    // do those operations after
    // the fonts are loaded here
    ....
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Error");
  });
```